# When reading data from Azure Data Lake using Power BI, can the same file on Data Lake be deleted/replaced?

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-lake

When reading data from Azure Data Lake using Power BI, can the same file on Data Lake be deleted/replaced ?

Comment: You're asking if the file can be deleted/replaced while you are actually in the process of reading it into Power BI?

Comment: No, I meant, once the file is read by Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

When using PowerBI to connect directly to ADLS, you can delete the underlying file you've extracting data from and your dashboards will still work (once you've loaded it into PowerBI).  If you attempt to refresh your data (from PowerBI desktop) after you've deleted the file, you'll get an error but can still view all of your old data. You can also continue to view your dashboard online after deleting the file.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.